# Which Django field should I use for longitude and latitude?

Tags: django, django-models, mapbox, geodjango

I am saving longitude and latitude as FloatField. But when I tried to use them on JS in the array I figured out that FloatField separates with a comma instead of a dot as should be on latitude or longitude. So it acts like four different elements in js.

js:

```
map.on('load', () => {
'coordinates': [
    [{{tour.departure.city.longitude}},{{tour.departure.city.latitude}}],
    [{{tour.arrival.city.longitude}},{{tour.arrival.city.latitude}}],
    // it will be like  [ 23, 0534 , 42, 1534]
    // but should be like [ 23.0534 , 42.1534]
    ]
});
```

models.py

```
class Tour(models.Model):

    latitude = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_("Latitude"))
    longitude= models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_("Longitude"))
```

I tried to save with dot but Django converted it to the comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [DECIMAL_SEPARATOR](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#std-setting-DECIMAL_SEPARATOR) setting. You may be inheriting a [country-specific](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/) (or [custom](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#std-setting-FORMAT_MODULE_PATH)) formatting.

If this doesn't work, please update your question to include the relevant settings.

Comment: It worked! Thank you. I set `USE_L10N` to False to avoid reformating decimal fields.